# Call a protectedmethods from another package?

Tags: java, methods, scope, protected

```
package1:
public class A{
    protected void Display(){
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}

package2:
import package1.*;

class C extends A{}

public class B{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        C var = new C();
        var.Display(); //error
    }
}
```

`C` is a subclass of `A`. And Access Modifier `protected` means the same package or by inheritance(can access from another package by subclasses). But when I try to call the `protected` method from another package. It didn't work.

Comment: You can call that method IN C, not through an instance of C IN B

Comment: thankyou, i did it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`protected` is visible to subclasses. If the class is not itself a subclass of `A`, it does not have access to the method (i.e., that class may not call or reference the method).

`B` is not a subclass of `A`. Even if the object it's calling the protected method on is an instance of `A`'s subclass, `B` itself does not have access to the method because it's not a subclass of `A`.

In other words, the call to `Display()` would be valid in `C`, not in `B` through an instance of `C`. Even from within `C`, it would only be allowed on a `C`'s own instances.

Comment: Thank you, I got it.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error because `Display` is a `protected` member and therefore it is visible in the child class of `A` whereas `B` is not a child class of `A`.

**package1**

```
package package1;
public class A{
    protected void Display(){
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

**package2**

```
 package package2;

import package1.A;

class C extends A {
    public void someMethod() {
        Display();// No error
    }
}
public class B {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        C var = new C();
        var.Display();// Error
    }
}
```

On a side note:

1. Follow [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) e.g. the method, `Display` should be named as `display`.
2. Try to post a compilation error-free code. The code you have posted has so many compilation errors e.g. you have missed the keyword, `package` in the package declaration.